# echarts line chart distorted when drawing two lines

Tags: echarts

I have the following data set

```
data = {
  "qr": [
    [
      "2020-07-28", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-07-31", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-04", 2
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-06", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-10", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-11", 12
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-12", 17
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-13", 15
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-14", 3
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-17", 9
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-21", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-24", 5
    ]
  ],
  "url": [
    [
      "2020-07-31", 4
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-03", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-05", 7
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-06", 2
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-07", 16
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-11", 1
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-13", 4
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-14", 24
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-17", 67
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-18", 2
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-19", 6
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-21", 10
    ],
    [
      "2020-08-24", 18
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm using the echarts to draw the line graph

```
graphData = Object.assign(graphData, {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        name: xAxis
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data:  data.url,
          type: 'line',
          name: 'Short URL',
          areaStyle: {},
          smooth: true
        },
        {
          data:  data.qr,
          type: 'line',
          name: 'QR Codes',
          areaStyle: {},
          smooth: true
        }
      ]
    });
```

But the graph generated is very distorted

[image]

The line with red colour is fine, but the one with the blue colour is very distorted.

Drawing a single line chart is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Echarts must updating only with [`setOption`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption) otherwise you will fights with very strange bugs. Echarts has difficult merge [procedure](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/099367a21540ad582d2a1bb9f76da2f06cd05ff9/src/model/OptionManager.js#L160) that to trigger the internal processes but calling `Object.assign` instead you skipping them.
2. The date dimension should pass to the Axis instead series. Please take a look at Echarts [short anatomy](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#ECharts%20Basic%20Concepts%20Overview).
3. When you trying to make chart with the different dates then you need to use different axes because it is not clear how to draw different dimensions on the same axis.

And at the end your hair will be soft and silky:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var data = {
  qr: [
    ["2020-07-28", 1],
    ["2020-07-31", 1],
    ["2020-08-04", 2],
    ["2020-08-06", 1],
    ["2020-08-10", 1],
    ["2020-08-11", 12],
    ["2020-08-12", 17],
    ["2020-08-13", 15],
    ["2020-08-14", 3],
    ["2020-08-17", 9],
    ["2020-08-21", 1],
    ["2020-08-24", 5],
  ],
  url: [
    ["2020-07-31", 4],
    ["2020-08-03", 1],
    ["2020-08-05", 7],
    ["2020-08-06", 2],
    ["2020-08-07", 16],
    ["2020-08-11", 1],
    ["2020-08-13", 4],
    ["2020-08-14", 24],
    ["2020-08-17", 67],
    ["2020-08-18", 2],
    ["2020-08-19", 6],
    ["2020-08-21", 10],
    ["2020-08-24", 18],
  ],
};

var option = {
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: [{
    id: 0,
    type: 'category',
    data: '',
  }, {
    id: 1,
    type: 'category',
    data: '',
    show: false, // hide second xAxis
  }],
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [{
      id: 'url',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      data: ["2020-07-31", 4],
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Short URL',
      areaStyle: {},
      smooth: true
    },
    {
      id: 'qr',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      data: ["2020-07-28", 1],
      type: 'line',
      name: 'QR Codes',
      areaStyle: {},
      smooth: true
    }
  ]
};

// set common config
myChart.setOption(option);

// set data later
myChart.setOption({
  xAxis: [{
    id: 0,
    data: data.qr.map(point => point[0])
  }, {
    id: 1,
    data: data.url.map(point => point[0])
  }],
  series: [{
    id: 'url',
    data: data.url.map(point => point[1])
  }, {
    id: 'qr',
    data: data.qr.map(point => point[1])
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the echarts behaves differently for dates with xAxis type as `category`. I need to change it to `time` and now it works fine.

```
graphData = Object.assign(graphData, {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        name: xAxis
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data:  data.url,
          type: 'line',
          name: 'Short URL',
          areaStyle: {},
          smooth: true
        },
        {
          data:  data.qr,
          type: 'line',
          name: 'QR Codes',
          areaStyle: {},
          smooth: true
        }
      ]
    });
```